# Autofac factory instantiation without parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am new at using Autofac, so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Let's say I have an abstract class FooBase with parameterless constructor, and an implementation thereof called Foo.

In my AP.Net MVC5 client code, I would like to be able to create an instance of an object of type FooBase (I have set up Autofac to resolve it to Foo).  The lifetime and scope of this instance is limited to my method, and I would like to do it in a fashion similar to calling a factory method if possible.

Currently I am making use of the DependencyResolver, but it seems a bit contrived.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

For example, here is what it currently looks like...

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    var foo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<FooBase>();
    Debug.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}
```

I am looking for something a little more like this...

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    var foo = IoC.Resolve<FooBase>();
    Debug.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply add a `Resolve` generic method onto your `DependencyResolver` class which in turn says `this.Current.GetService<...>()`? On another note are you not able to inject `Foo` into the constructor of your class? This would enable you to move away from using a `ServiceLocator` pattern which would mean you wouldn't have to call 'GetService' in the middle of a method as all of your dependencies would be resolved before the class was constructed?

Comment: Hi.  No, unfortunately neither constructor injection or property injection will be appropriate in this case.  The class contains runtime logic which decides when a new instance of a class should be instantiated or when an existing version should be "fetched" from some other place.

Comment: @StephenRoss I was trying to find out if Autofac already has some standard way of doing this, before rolling my own.

Comment: No problem was just a suggestion. In that case if you were wanting to call `GetService` easier then I'd suggest wrapping it in a `Resolve` generic method yourself which can then call `Current.GetService<...>()`. Means that you don't need to expose `Current` either as I'm expecting that this is your actual `Container`, which will help slightly. Nope as far as I was aware you'd actually have to call `GetService` and was something that I had to do previously as like you we were unable to do construction injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the Service Locator [which is an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html), you can simply inject a factory which allows you to create an instance of the dependency if/when you want. The simplest way is to inject a [`Func<FooBase>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx). Autofac [supports this natively](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html). If you just register `FooBase`, AutoFac knows how to inject  `Func<FooBase>`. Here is an example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Func<FooBase> m_FooBaseFactory;

    public TestClass(Func<FooBase> factory)
    {
        m_FooBaseFactory = factory;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var foo = m_FooBaseFactory();
        //consume foo here
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this approach as it does not require me to create delegates inside my service components.  To anyone reading this in future, this reference on implicit relationship types is also quite handy http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [delegate factories](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)

First declare the delegate factory in the type that you want to build at runtime:

```
public class TestService
{
    public delegate TestService Factory();
    //other methods....
}
```

Then you can inject the factory as any other dependency, ex:

```
public class ExampleController
{
    private TestService.Factory _factory;
    public ExampleController(TestService.Factory factory)                
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public OtherMethod()
    {
        var serviceInstance = _factory();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the approach to go +1. However, (IMO) using `Func<T>` is easier.